# Why doesn't fread() into my struct work?

Tags: c

I have the following code that reads from a file into a struct and into an arrary. When I try to print the data in the struct it isn't what I would expect. The array prints what would be expected, the first two characters in the file.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)){
        uint8_t magic[2];   /* the magic number used to identify the BMP file:
                     0x42 0x4D (Hex code points for B and M).
                     The following entries are possible:
                     BM - Windows 3.1x, 95, NT, ... etc
                     BA - OS/2 Bitmap Array
                     CI - OS/2 Color Icon
                     CP - OS/2 Color Pointer
                     IC - OS/2 Icon
                     PT - OS/2 Pointer. */
} bmp_header_t;


bool
bmp_get_header_from_file(FILE *fp, bmpfile_t *bmp)
{
       fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
       char magic[1];

       fread(magic, 1, 2, fp);
       printf("magic is: %c, %c\n", magic[0], magic[1]);

       fread(&bmp->header, 1, 2, fp); 
       printf("magic is: %c, %c\n", bmp->header.magic[0], bmp->header.magic[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the first `fread`, you advance the read position of the file, so the second `fread` will read the next two bytes. You'll need to add another `fseek` before the second read.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `char magic[1]` gives you *one* byte, not two. Reading two bytes into that is a definite no-no.

Second, the subsequent `fread` will attempt to read the *next* two bytes in the file rather than the first two, because the first `fread` has advanced the file pointer.

Something like this would be better:

```
   char magic[2];

   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
   fread(magic, 1, 2, fp);
   printf("magic is: %c, %c\n", magic[0], magic[1]);

   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
   fread(&bmp->header, 1, 2, fp); 
   printf("magic is: %c, %c\n", bmp->header.magic[0], bmp->header.magic[1]);
```

Comment: The compiler probably padded that buffer to 4/8/16 bytes, so he got lucky, but yeah, that's unreliable behavior.